# Merge [history] and [historical-change] tags

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-synonyms

There are several tags that are associated with the background of a word:

- [[etymology]](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/etymology/info)
- [[origin-unknown]](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/origin-unknown/info)
- [[phrase-origin]](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/phrase-origin/info)
- [[history]](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/history/info)
- [[historical-change]](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/historical-change/info)

But for [historical-change](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-change), both the definition page and the [tagged questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-change) don't indicate to me that it merits distinction from either [etymology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) nor [history](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history).  I therefore recommend [historical-change](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-change) be merged with [history](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history), since it is the closer of the two.

Does anyone see a use for keeping them separate?  If so, clarification of the distinction(s) between them should be added to their respective info pages (linked above in bullets).

Comment: Assuming there are sufficient properly tagged questions, `historical-change` suggests to me questions about words/phrases from old times still in use today, with a probable evolution in meaning. `history` could be about similar questions, but it could also be about questions featuring words that are now extinct. I think there's no harm in keeping the two tags separate.